# Difficulty creating a new matrix with some specifications in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that is 11 x 2 in size:

```
M = 
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 4     1
 1     2
 2     2
 3     2
 4     2
 5     2
 4     3
 5     3
```

I would like to create a new matrix that is of size 7 x 5.  This matrix should be filled in such a way where each row of `M` denotes where I would like to set this new matrix to be 1.  Specifically, position (1,1) the result must be 1, the next position (2,1) is 1 up until the last position (5,3) which is 1.

How do I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: what you are looking for is possible. But explain in detail what your input is and what you want to get. Examples of input and output will better explain.

Comment: How are related the 11*2 matrix and the new 7*5 matrix? What and why???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite easy to achieve using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  You can convert the row and column locations to a single linear index, then use this and assign `1` to each location of your output matrix.  I'm going to assume that the other locations are zero (`0`).  In other words, do this assuming that `A` is the `7 x 5` output matrix you have defined and the matrix in your problem definition is `M` (the `11 x 2` matrix):

```
ind = sub2ind([7 5], M(:,1), M(:,2));
A = zeros(7, 5);
A(ind) = 1;
```

`A` is thus:

```
A =

 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and use the elements of your matrix you defined in your problem as elements to create non-zero entries while the rest are zero.  In our case, we will set each location of this sparse matrix defined by the values of `M` to be `1`.  We then convert the matrix back to its proper form using [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html).  As such:

```
Asparse = sparse(M(:,1), M(:,2), 1, 7, 5);
A = full(Asparse);
```

We get what we expect like we saw in our first method:

```
A =

 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, i really need to study harder

Comment: @PepeLópez - Not a problem at all.  I'm here to answer questions.. especially regarding MATLAB :)

Comment: +1 Very complete answer